# Optimization of a large number of meshes

Tags: three.js

How to facilitate rendering a large number of "similar" mesh?

So far I've found the following:
1. Disconnect the matrix calculation of the mesh before each shot:
mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
and calculate the matrix when changing the rotation or position.

Disable frusum culling (I do not need it. All the meshes are always in the field of view camera)
And the following questions:
Meshes - pieces of terrain, they have the same material, except for the texture. Is there a way to use one material for all selected meshes, but when rendering change only the necessary data

And what else there are ways to optimize?

Comment: you can merge the meshes that share the same material (ie. texture). Look at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/GeometryUtils

Comment: I can not, they are dynamically loaded and removed independently

Comment: well if it is terrain that you want to optimize take a look at http://zephyrosanemos.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse materials, textures, geometries and almost anything in THREE.JS ...

for your terrain, create one material and then create as many meshes using this material as you like.

**Edit:** if you have more than one texture, you will have to use one material per each texture you want to use. If each mesh needs to have it's own texture different from all others, that you won't be able to optimize materials, but I don't believe this is your case.

Merging geometries is great optimization trick, if you can't do that at least reuse geometry in the same way as materials.

Comment: As a material used given that for every mesh it only has different textures? How to change the texture of the mesh before rendering?